# codeigniter multiple inputs in table

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have 2 inputs with same name
this is my view

```
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="serv[]" >
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="serv[]" >
        <input type="hidden" id="dr_id" name="d_id">
```

my controller function is

```
public function submit_2()
{

        $data = array(
            'service_name' => $this->input->post('serv'),
            'dr_id' => $this->input->post('d_id'),
            );
        $this->insert_model->service_insert($data);}
```

my model is

```
 function service_insert($data){
   $this->db->insert('services', $data);  
}
```

i am getting error

what i want[image]
i want this result.

Comment: You need `loop statement` for this..

Comment: $this->input->post('serv'); this variable for array

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = $this->input->post('serv'); //it will contain value in arrray format
foreach($arr as $k=>$v)
{
    $data = array(
            'service_name' => $v,
            'dr_id' => $this->input->post('d_id'),
            );
        $this->insert_model->service_insert($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `insert_batch()`

```
public function submit_2()
{
    $services = $this->input->post('serv');
    $data = [];
    foreach($services as $service)
    {
        $data[] = array(
        'service_name' => $service,
        'dr_id' => $this->input->post('d_id'),
        );

     }
        $this->insert_model->service_insert($data);
 }
```

**Your Model**

```
function service_insert($data){
   $this->db->insert_batch('services', $data);  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use below code in controller

```
    $servData = $this->input->post('serv');
    if(is_array($servData))
    {
        foreach ($servData as $serv)
        {
            if(!empty($serv))
            {
                $data[] = array(
                    'service_name' => $serv,
                    'dr_id' => $this->input->post('d_id'),
                );
            }
        }
    }
    $this->insert_model->service_insert($data);
```