# How To Implode Multiple Select Options Input Array in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have select dropdown with multiple select options here is in view :-

```
<select name="users[]" id="users" multiple>
<option value="1">John</option>
<option value="2">Doe</option>
<option value="3">karan</option>    
</select>
```

Now in Controller I did this input array implode and store in database like that :-

```
 $data['users'] = implode(",",$this->input->post('users', TRUE));
```

But Cideigniter Give me Error :-

> implode() invalid arguments passed

Thanks For Your Help.

Comment: what does `var_dump($this->input->post('users', true));` tell you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [codeigniter multiple inputs in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36593713/codeigniter-multiple-inputs-in-table)

Comment: What you're doing is right. I think your form method is "GET" it should be "POST"

Comment: No 100% POST method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay  After Little Bit effort i got it ,i put implode array in variable $users and store in database , like that

```
$users=implode(',',$this->input('users'));

 $data['users'] = $users;
```

That's work for me  and for those who find answer of this question , Thanks For Whole Community

Answer (score 1):

you can use `$_POST('users')` instead of `$this->input->post('users', TRUE)`